# Entity annotation attributes do not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, storing-data

Here is my entity:

```
[Table( Name = "PdfMeta" )]
public class Meta
{
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "TotalPages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "PdfPath")]
    public string PdfUri { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "ImagePath")]
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "SplittedPdfPath")]
    public string SplittedFolderUri { get; set; }

}
```

Here is code from context:

```
      public DbSet<Meta> PdfMeta { get; set; }
```

Why new table (Metas) has created with ImageUri, PdfUri ... columns? I know that this was done  by convention but I have explisitly specifyed table and columns.

Comment: Do you perhaps use additionally the fluent configuration?

Comment: yes, I use generic Repositories with IDbContext, ...

Comment: There are two `ColumnAttribute` make sure that you are using the right one: `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Name` property of `ColumnAttribute` has only getter defined. Pass column name in constructor instead:

```
[Table("PdfMeta")]
public class Meta
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("TotalPages")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [Column("PdfPath")]
    public string PdfUri { get; set; }

    [Column("ImagePath")]
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }

    [Column("SplittedPdfPath")]
    public string SplittedFolderUri { get; set; }
}
```

BTW `ColumnAttribute` defined in EntityFramework.dll. Looks like you have referenced `ColumnAttribute` from System.Data.Linq.dll

Comment: @NET possibly you are using wrong attribute. Verify, it should be from EF assembly from namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema`